# The Saba Kadisha's opinion on using a lemon for an esrog

Tags: lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I remember seeing in the Igros Moshe a while back which quotes the Saba Kadisha's opinion that one can technically use a lemon instead of an esrog. It was a side idea in the Igros Moshe. Does anyone know where the Saba Kadisha's opinion is stated and his reasons?

Answer (score 6):

In [Orach Chaim 4 siman 123](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14677&st=&pgnum=217), Rav Moshe stronglly asserts that a lemon is not kosher for an esrog and says kol shekein a canary palm is not good for lulav.

Later in the [tshuva](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14677&st=&pgnum=218) he quotes the Saba Kadisha in his tshuvos chelek 3  siman 12 who seems to lean to possibly allowing the lemon to be used as an esrog, but points out that even he would not allow the canary palm, the focus of his tshuva there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I really wanted to see the Saba Kadisha's tshuva but cant find it using the ones detailed.I remember a few years ago looking it up but never found it.

Comment: And it looks like hebrewbooks does not have the chelek you need to see the tshuva inside. Good luck!

Comment: np,yea I know still looking,I think I may have found it in his other Shu"t that Rav Moshe doesn't mention,need to delve further.